# Cannot clone from git.gnome.org

Tags: git, github, gnome

I am working on an Ubuntu OS.
I have tried cloning several repositories from git.gnome.org such as this -

`git clone git://git.gnome.org/newcomers-tutorial
Cloning into 'newcomers-tutorial'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.gnome.org:
git.gnome.org[0: 209.132.180.184]: errno=Connection timed out`

And even tried with http:// -

`git clone http://git.gnome.org/newcomers-tutorial
Cloning into 'newcomers-tutorial'...
fatal: http://git.gnome.org/newcomers-tutorial/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

whereas if i clone any other repo from github it is successfully cloned.
Such as -

`git clone https://github.com/arduino/Arduino.git
Cloning into 'Arduino'...
remote: Counting objects: 53558, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (617/617), done.
^Cceiving objects:  11% (5996/53558), 23.67 MiB | 1.41 MiB/s`

I am working behind a proxy and already have set it by -

```
git config --global http.proxy $http_proxy
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The git protocol uses a special port (9418) which, is you are working behind a proxy, is likely to be blocked.

As for http cloning, the [web page of the `newcomers-tutorial` repo](https://git.gnome.org/browse/newcomers-tutorial/) mentions an *https* url, not an http one:

```
git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/newcomers-tutorial
```

Make sure to set your https proxy as well first:

```
git config --global https.proxy $http_proxy
```

Comment: Thanks it worked by https but that was just an example and i'm facing this problem in general, basically when i use jhbuild it clones repos and then also i get the same error, could you suggest something about it?

Comment: @Krist 'jhbuild' was not part of your original question. Your original question was why the cloned failed and I believe I have adequately answered it. Simply make sure jhbuild uses the right urls `https://git.gnome.org/browse/<yourRepo>`

Comment: Yeah you did answer it and that was correct, just wanted to know how to solve same problem with jhbuild. So should i ask a new fresh question?

Comment: @Krist yes, with details like your OS, the version of git and the version of jhbuild. Plus, you can include a link back to this first question, for context.