# jhbuild repository cloning failed

Tags: git, gnome, jhbuild

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 and jhbuild ver 3.12.0 and git version 1.7.9.5.

Earlier I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494361/cannot-clone-from-git-gnome-org/) and it was resolved, now the same problem(I suppose it's the same problem) arises when i build using jhbuild,being behind a proxy it cannot clone the repo which has got git:// in the URL because the URL requires to be either of http:// OR https:// . Since cloning process is automatic by jhbuild it results into an error as following -

```
$ jhbuild build glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: glib -> gvfs -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: glib -> glib-networking -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: glib -> dconf -> glib
*** Checking out itstool *** [1/5]
*** Skipping itstool (package and dependencies not updated) *** [1/5]
*** Checking out yelp-xsl *** [2/5]
git clone git://git.gnome.org/yelp-xsl
Cloning into 'yelp-xsl'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.gnome.org:
git.gnome.org[0: 209.132.180.184]: errno=Connection timed out

*** Error during phase checkout of yelp-xsl: ########## Error running git clone git://git.gnome.org/yelp-xsl *** [2/5]
```

What could be the possible solution to it ?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildGnome) links to [a blog post describing how to set up JHBuild such that it uses the HTTP URLs instead of the git ones](http://blog.aurabindo.in/getting-started-with-gnome-development/). From there, you can use your HTTP proxy.

Essentially, set up your config file to replace the repository URLs:

```
repos['git.gnome.org'] = 'https://git.gnome.org/browse/'  
repos['git.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/'  
repos['wayland.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/wayland'  
repos['gstreamer.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer'  
repos['pulseaudio.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pulseaudio'  
repos['telepathy.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/telepathy'  
repos['modemmanager.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/ModemManager'  
repos['git.savannah.nongnu.org'] = 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/'  
repos['github.com'] = 'https://github.com/'
```

Let me also link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37862894/2015768) to properly maintain links between similar subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I also recently had this problem.
The solution is a VPN / Proxy.