# jhbuild build throwing 407 authentication error

Tags: proxy, jhbuild

I'm trying to install jhbuild. When I give `jhbuild build` command it gives me error -

```
jhbuild build: could not download https://git.gnome.org/browse/jhbuild/plain/modulesets/gnome-apps-3.18.modules: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required>
```

I'm behind a college proxy and Ubuntu 14.04. How do I find a way around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your college proxy has some kind of authentication. Put the correct proxy settings in environment by adding this

```
export http_proxy="http://[username]:[password]@[proxy.server.com]:[port]"
export https_proxy="http://[username]:[password]@[proxy.server.com]:[port]"
```

in your .bashrc or any other init configuration files. Even after if it shows the same error, I came across a good tool [proGY](https://github.com/aki237/proGY) (An intermediate proxy authenticator).
Also you will have to set your proxy url as above in git config also

```
 git config --global http.proxy http://[username]:[password]@[proxy.server.com]:[port]
 git config --global https.proxy http://[username]:[password]@[proxy.server.com]:[port]
```

If you college doesn't have other open ports as git protocol uses it, you should explicitly say jhbuild to use http:// git clone urls instead of git:// clone URLS.

```
 repos['git.gnome.org'] = 'https://git.gnome.org/browse/'  
 repos['git.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/'  
 repos['wayland.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/wayland'
 repos['gstreamer.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer'  
 repos['pulseaudio.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pulseaudio'  
 repos['telepathy.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/telepathy'  
 repos['modemmanager.freedesktop.org'] = 'http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/ModemManager'  
 repos['git.savannah.nongnu.org'] = 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/'  
 repos['github.com'] = 'https://github.com/'
```

in your jhbuildrc file (in ~/.config/jhbuildrc)